# How to test multiple implementations of a common interface without duplicating the testcode in Go?

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, parameterized-tests

How would I streamline the following testing scenario in Go?

Say I have some interface `I` with a corresponding implementation `A` and most of my tests for A basically look like:

```golang
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    instances := setupI(5)
    // actual testing code...
}

func setupI(n: int) []I {
    instances := make([]I, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        instances[i] = A { ... } // concrete implementation A used here
    }
    return instances
}
```

Some other tests are specific to the details hidden behind the interface `I`, so tests like the following are used instead:

```golang
func TestSomethingForA(t *testing.T) {
    instance := A { ... }
    // actual testing code...
}
```

Say now I have two more implementation for `I` named `B` and `C`.
How do I also test `B` and `C` with all the tests of the first kind? Of course a simple way would be to copy the common testcode two more times, and, for example, add a parameter to `setupI(...)` to initialize instances with the different implementations. However, I would like to avoid copying the code and having to keep three different places in sync down the road. Any better ideas?

Comment: Why don't you just add instances of B and C to the existing instances slice?

Comment: Oh, just by the nature of the tests in my scenario, each testcase just requires a different number of instances of the same underlying implementation. So instances is expected to always hold a many `A` values or many `B` values, but not a combination of both.

I could use an array of arrays, but then again I have to add a loop in each of my testcases as boilerplate code.